# Android HTTP Post File with Parameters

Tags: java, android, http, post

I need to post a file, using the following rules:

```
$ curl -X POST https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads \
-H "Authorization: Bearer 83ebeabdec09f6670863766f792ead24d61fe3f9" \
-F activity_type=ride \
-F file=@temp.gpx \
-F data_type=gpx
```

I have the Authorization code, I have the file.
I've seen a lot of examples on stack overflow, but, I don't know how to all of them together, and I don't know what the "-F" and "-H" should be passed as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, I discovered that the "-H" stands for "header", and has it's own place:

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads");

        try {
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
            FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(FilePath));


            httppost.setHeader("Authorization:", "Bearer " + Token);

            entity.addPart("activity_type", new StringBody("run"));
            entity.addPart("file", bin);
            entity.addPart("data_type", new StringBody("GPX"));

            httppost.setEntity(entity);



            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            Log.i("Kenyan Runner", "Response of file upload: " + responseBody);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("Kenyan Runner", e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Kenyan Runner", e.toString());
        }finally {
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
```